# When is an account in Polkadot / Kusama reaped?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, polkadot

Polkadot has the concept of reaping (killing) accounts whose balance falls below an existential threshold. What is that threshold and how often is the reaping process executed on the network to purge it of low-balance accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reaping happens as soon as an account's balance is reduced below that threshold. There is no delay, the reaping is part of the transaction that reduced the balance.

The threshold is 0.01 KSM - on Polkadot it may differ. You can always check the current existential deposit as registered on-chain through the [Polkadot UI](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate/constants) by going into Chain State, then Constants, then `balances` and then to `existensialDeposit`:

[image]